# I need a formula for excel for counting figure if in a particular month

Tags: excel

I need a formula for Excel. In column A, I have a dates in a format of dd/mm/yyyy. In column D I have a figure e.g.: 3.

I need a formula which will choose all the ones of January and count the figures in column D? Can someone help me please?

Comment: **1.** Working with Excel spreadsheets doesn't exactly qualify as computer programming IMHO. Voted to close as off-topic. **2.** That being said, it's usually expected of askers that they have done some research or attempted to solve their problem on their own. Your question doesn't give any hint that you've done so. Downvoted because of that; SO is not a do-my-work-for-me-for-free service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is data in rows 1-20 then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(A1:A20)=1)*(D1:D20))
```

For example:

[image]